# Get private properties with TypeDescriptor

Tags: c#, reflection, private-members, typedescriptor

I would like to get private properties of the class using **TypeDescriptor** in c#.

So far calling

```
TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(myType);
```

returns only public, non-static properties.

I have not found a way how to influence **GetProperties** or **GetProvider** methods to force them to return other than "default" (public, non-static) members.

Please do not suggest reflection (I am well aware of BindingFlags) unless it gives me a **PropertyDescriptor** object.

Comment: I don't know of any way that this could be done with `TypeDescriptor`, without using reflection. What's the reason for you not wanting to use reflection?

Comment: TypeDescriptor is much much faster if you need to do invoke

Comment: Unfortunately it can't be done with TypeDescriptor. You'll need to resort to reflection.

Comment: Furthermore, if it needs to be accessible externally it should be public, not private.

Comment: @MarcGravell - so when I said _"Unfortunately it can't be done with TypeDescriptor. You'll need to resort to reflection."_, I was correct. You can do it with a custom extension of TypeDescriptor that uses reflection, which is not the same as using the existing TypeDescriptor class without reflection (which is what he wanted to do).

Comment: @Polynomial you were *half* correct. You can "educate" `TypeDescriptor` to return what the OP wants, but you need to use reflection *for the implementation*. The **calling** code, however, would only know about `TypeDescriptor` and `PropertyDescriptor`.

Comment: Depends on what he means by "faster". If he means in terms of performance, there's still a reflection overhead. In fact, there's more overhead because you're just wrapping reflection in something else. If he means cleaner, then I guess it's maybe a little cleaner? I don't really see much difference.

Comment: Properties I want to use are marked as internal and for some reason they should stay like this (however to get a quick fix we change the visibility for a couple properties we need the most).

Comment: Re performance - by default they are *about* the same; however, via TypeDescriptor you can actually make PropertyDescriptor *out-perform* PropertyInfo (by *removing* the reflection); this is exactly what HyperDescriptor sets out to do /cc @Polynomial

Comment: Our case scenario, we have a collection of object of the same type and we need to produce sql queries based on this info, and we have a mapping of properties to column names. So now we want to keep it generic and we use revoke with PropertyInfo/PropertyDescriptor objects. Tests shows PropertyDescriptor is faster by times.

Comment: In that case, you might indeed find the HyperDescriptor code useful, however *personally* I would be tempted to look at meta-programming at the *Info level; an example of that (in both directions) can be found in dapper-dot-net (says someone who wrote the scary IL code for both HyperDescriptor and dapper-dot-net).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do that you would have to write and register a custom `TypeDescriptionProvider` that **does** use reflection. You can certainly, however, do this - you can even have `PropertyDescriptor` instances that actually talk to fields (instead of properties). You will also probably need to write your own bespke `PropertyDescriptor` implementation since `ReflectPropertyDescriptor` is `internal` (you could perhaps use reflection to obtain that). Ultimately, you ***will*** have to use reflection *for the implementation*, but you can achieve the requirement that `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Type)` returns `PropertyDescriptor` instances that you want.

You can do this for types outside your control, too. It should be stressed, however, that your intent is unusual.

If you were using the `.GetProperties(instance)` overload, then you can also do this by implementing `ICustomTypeDescriptor` which is simpler than a full `TypeDescriptionProvider`.

For an example of hooking a bespoke provider, see [HyperDescriptor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HyperPropertyDescriptor.aspx)

Comment: I've seen this idea before, looks scary. Do you have examples?

Comment: @BanditoBunny I already edited in an example of hyperdescriptor - any use?

Comment: Perfect, it comes out we had already a custom implementation of the HyperTypeProvider (using il code) and we have changed BindingFlags for property extraction block and used our custom HyperTypeProvider instead of default one.

Answer (score 3):

You may create your own `CustomPropertyDescriptor` which gets the info from `PropertyInfo`.

Recently I need to get the `PropertyDescriptorCollection` of nonpublic properties.

After I used `type.GetProperties(BindingFlags. Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)` to get the nonpublic properties, then I use the following class to create the corresponding `PropertyDescriptor`.

```
class CustomPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo;
    public CustomPropertyDescriptor(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
        : base(propertyInfo.Name, Array.ConvertAll(propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true), o => (Attribute)o))
    {
        this.propertyInfo = propertyInfo;
    }
    public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override Type ComponentType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.propertyInfo.DeclaringType;
        }
    }

    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        return this.propertyInfo.GetValue(component, null);
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get
        {
            return !this.propertyInfo.CanWrite;
        }
    }

    public override Type PropertyType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.propertyInfo.PropertyType;
        }
    }

    public override void ResetValue(object component)
    {
    }

    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
        this.propertyInfo.SetValue(component, value, null);
    }

    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```