# Why isn't TypeDescriptor.GetProperties() working for me?

Tags: c#

I have some code that creates a couple of Person objects and then adds those objects to a List.  I'm trying to output the properties and values to the console by using `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties()`.  I'm not getting any output, though.  When I step through in debug, the descriptor `foreach` loop just acts like there are no properties in my `Person` object.  However, when I look at the object in debug, I can see all the properties for the object and they all have values (i.e. name = "Mark", age = "40", etc).  Can someone tell me why it isn't working when, clearly, there are properties and values in my objects?

Here's the code that I'm using for this particular part:

```
foreach (var person in People)
{
     foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(person))
     {
          string name = descriptor.Name;
          object value = descriptor.GetValue(person);
          Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", name, value);
     }
}
```

EDIT: Here is the class and program I'm tinkering with.  Basically just a program that let's you drag and drop a particular XML file to the form with the intent of printing the object's properties and their values to the console.

Here is my Person class:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
     public class Person
     {

         //Must have zero parameter constructor for Object => XML serialization.
         public Person(){}

         public Person(string name, int age, string gender, bool hasChildren, 

         List<Person> children = null )
         {
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
            Gender = gender;
            HasChildren = hasChildren;
            Children = children;
        }

        private string Name { get; set; }
        private int Age { get; set; }
        private string Gender { get; set; }
        private bool HasChildren { get; set; }
        private List<Person> Children { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my Program:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var People = new List<Person>();
            var ChildrenList = new List<Person>();
            var hasChildren = false;
            var ofd = new OpenFileDialog { Filter = "XML|*.xml" };
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;

            var xdoc = XDocument.Load(ofd.FileName);
            foreach (var element in xdoc.Descendants("People").Elements("Person"))
            {
                var name = element.Element("Name").Value;
                var age = Convert.ToInt32(element.Element("Age").Value);
                var gender = element.Element("Name").Value;
                var xmlNode = element.Descendants("Children").FirstOrDefault(xe => xe.Elements("Child").Any());
                if (xmlNode != null)
                {
                    hasChildren = true;
                    foreach (var child in element.Descendants("Children").Descendants("Child"))
                    {
                        var ChildName = child.Element("Name").Value;
                        var ChildAge = Convert.ToInt32(child.Element("Age").Value);
                        var ChildGender = child.Element("Gender").Value;
                        ChildrenList.Add(new Person(ChildName, ChildAge, ChildGender, false));
                    }
                }
                People.Add(new Person(name, age, gender, hasChildren, ChildrenList));
            }

            foreach (var person in People)
            {
                foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(person))
                {
                    string name = descriptor.Name;
                    object value = descriptor.GetValue(person);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", name, value);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Sure thing, Mr. Skeet.  I'll provide the program and classes involved.

Comment: Can you post the Person class?

Comment: I am not really sure about that, but did you try to change do access modify from Person's attributes to `protected` ?

Comment: There's no need for this to be a Windows Forms app. A short console app is much simpler to aid people reproducing the problem. The code you've posted isn't even complete, because it relies on what the designer has created for you.

Comment: And that's fine for your own purposes, but when posting code for others to try to reproduce a problem, it's helpful to provide a minimal but complete example.

Comment: @JonSkeet You're correct. This was just a little program I threw together to practice working with XML. Then, as an afterthought, I also wanted see what was in the objects that I had created. I had used TypeDescriptor.GetProperties before on another test class, so I just copied it into this one.  Since the program was so short, I posted it, instead of writing a new one.  I'll do better next time. I promise! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The properties of your `Person` class are private; `TypeDescriptor` returns only public properties.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks!  I'll mark the answer as soon as the timer is up.  Seens counter-intuitive for TypeDescriptor to only return public properties, though.  Heh, I want to see all properties!  Thanks, again!

Comment: this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900546/get-private-properties-with-typedescriptor shows that you can do what you want.. but you will need to create your own CustomTypeDescriptor.

Comment: @KevinJ, why do you want to make these properties private anyway? It doesn't seem to make much sense for this class...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Just because ReSharper told me to.  I was getting tired of looking at the little green squiggly lines :-)